# How to add grid lines at specific position to a plot?

Tags: r, data-visualization

On an existing plot, how do I add a horizontal grid line at vertical location 0. I can add lines using the `lines` function. However, that line will impact my legend.

Comment: if you're worried about adding a line impacting a legend it sounds like you might be using `ggplot`.  Can you please provide reproducible code corresponding to a simple example?

Comment: also cross-posted to r-help.  Please pick one or the other ...

Answer (score 8):

Did you try `abline(0, 0, lty=2)`?

Comment: Or `abline(h=0,lty=2)` might be easier to interpret.